# Why does TextEdit reject a document's permissions after being launched via FreePascal's TProcess on Max OS X Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, permissions, freepascal, textedit

I'm attempting to launch TextEdit using TProcess, giving it a text file that has just been written and closed by the calling program which is a command line program invoked on Terminal.

The first time I run this (see excerpts below), it works. This case is when TextEdit has not yet been used since the computer was restarted.

In every subsequent trial after that, after TextEdit has been used before, TextEdit reurns a modal error message saying:

```
"The document “DocName.PRN” could not be opened. You don’t have permission."
```

But using GetInfo I find the permissions are perfectly normal, and I have no dificulty opening the file with TextEdit 'manually'.

Because TextEdit gets launched and finds the document, I doubt there's anything wrong with the launch itself. I did try launching synchronously and that didn't change TextEdit's permissions message, but did require me to Force Quit TextEdit, after which the calling program would hang (fail to terminate but do nothing).

Anybody know what's going on here, and how to fix it?

```
...
    procedure launch (prm :array of string; syn :LaunchSyncType);
    var
        X   :integer;
        Proc: TProcess;
    begin
        Proc := TProcess.Create(nil);
        with Proc do begin
            try
                Executable:= prm[0];    {exe;}
                for X := 1 to high(prm) do
                    Parameters.Add(prm[X]);
                InheritHandles := False;
                for X := 1 to GetEnvironmentVariableCount do
                    Environment.Add(GetEnvironmentString(X));
                ShowWindow := swoShow; {used by Windows only}
                if syn = Synchronous then
                    Options := Options + [poWaitOnExit]
                else begin   {asynchronous}
                    Options := [];
                end;
                Execute;
            finally
                Free;
            end;
        end;
    end;
...
    launch( ['/Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit',
            '/Users/lor/LorDev/LOR/DocName.PRN'],
            Asynchronous );
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I followed the use case, but the problem is probably due to sandboxing. When a sandboxed process creates a subprocess, the subprocess inherits the sandbox, but it doesn't inherit any temporary permissions added by PowerBox (the open dialog).

Comment: @Ken that's an interesting suggestion. I have used the same method (as above) a few times calling other programs, Adobe's PDF Reader, the Open command, and several programs I've written, and none have had any similar problem. However, I will try setting InheritHandles to true and see what happens.

Comment: @Ken Setting `InheritHandles := True` did not help anything. I'm getting around the problem for now by launching `/usr/bin/open` instead of TextEdit, but that only works because my document name suffix is .PRN which is setup with TextEdit as the default open handler. It won't help any document name suffix which doesn't have an appropriate default opener.

Comment: First, `/usr/bin/open` just uses the Launch Services API. You can and should use that API directly rather than invoking `/usr/bin/open`. Second, whether you use Launch Services or `/usr/bin/open`, you can force a document to be sent to an application even if that application doesn't declare that it accepts that document type. Lastly, I doubt that `InheritHandles` has anything to with what I suggested about the sandbox. Your subprocess simply isn't allowed to access the file (by path) because it's sandboxed and not granted access to it in one of the supported ways.

Comment: @Ken, The Launch Services API is available to Swift or Objective-C as supported by Xcode, but this program is written in Free Pascal, because of its (claimed) cross-platform compatibility. Free Pascal provides the TProcess class as demonstrated in my question. It is possible with much more effort, to implement links to the Apple API in a custom class for the purpose. The Pascal TProcess class should provide the interface, but it is a function of TextEdit that prevents the success. Note how it does work the first time after restart, but not thereafter. The sandbox issue is thus contraindicated.

Comment: @Ken  I've found another strange behavior with the TProcess class - Multiple TextEdit processes launched by it (several test runs) become separate enduring dormant processes, whereas the Open launched trials are all handled by the single dormant TextEdit process from the first trial, like opening a different or same file after closing the prior file in TextEdit. 
This does implicate some possible sandboxing effect, in that the TextEdit processes launched by TProcess are not known to OSX as normal processes. They are sub-processes that do not terminate even after their launcher terminates.

Answer (score 0):

@Ken Research following your suggestion regarding Launch Services, convinces me the TProcess class as provided by FreePascal launches TextEdit as a new instance rather than using the existing instance, if any. This creates the problematic separate dormant processes and permissions breach. That approach is likely somehow appropriate to a Windows environment with TProcess attempting cross platform compatibility. The class in its present form does not provide an option to control this behavior. Therefore having TProcess launch TextEdit is unsuited to my project on OS X. Alternatively using the Open command with option -e (force TextEdit) is a quick and easy solution to my problem here. Thanks for the direction you gave me.

My launch code now looks like this:

```
launch( ['/usr/bin/open', '-e',
        '/Users/lor/LorDev/LOR/'+DocName+'.PRN'],
        Asynchronous );
```

Comment: Tprocess also models *nix perfectly. What you are using is probably closer to Windows' shellexecute, which is not abstracted by FPC/Lazarus either. You might also want to look at Lazarus' OpenDocument and similar functions